# Nested component not visible

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new to Angular 2 and my nested components are not visible or even processed. 
Can you please help? I think i might haven't declared any directive....
My main.ts :

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';  
import {MatchListComponent} from "./match/match.component"; 
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/http';

bootstrap(
  MatchListComponent,
   [ HTTP_PROVIDERS ]
 );
```

My MatchListComponent looks like that :

```
  @Component({
       selector: "matches",
       template: `
          <table class="table">
            <match-row *ngFor="#list of matches" match="list" >
            </match-row>
          </table>
       `,
       providers: [MatchService]
    })
    export class MatchListComponent implements OnInit...
```

No match-row becomes displayed, but about 150 of them are present in the dom

```
Edit: match-row

@Component({
   selector: "match-row",
   template: `
        <tr >
          <td>
             {{match.matchday.number}}
          </td>
          <td>
              {{match.displayValue}}
          </td>
        </tr>
   `,
   providers: [TrainerService, MatchdayService]
})
export class MatchRowComponent ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `let` instead of `#` in your `*ngFor` and I'm assuming your `match` is an input on `match-row`.  So your

```
<match-row *ngFor="#list of matches" match="list"</match-row>
```

should be

```
<match-row *ngFor="let list of matches" [match]="list" ></match-row>
```

To pass in variables on `()Input`s you must wrap the name in square brackets.  Just like outputs are wrapped in parentheses.  Inputs can be left without the square brackets  when passing in string literals, not variables.

Hope that helps.

**EDIT:**

With the code for `match-row` added, there is a much simpler way to do this.  There isn't really a reason to make this a separate component.  Move your rows into the main component to iterate on it this way:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr *ngFor="let match of matches">
        <td>{{match.matchday.number}}</td>
        <td>{{match.displayValue}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you insist on having the display data in another component, try moving the `<tr>` back to the main component since it is each row you want separated out.   It would look something like this:

```
<table class="table">
  <tr *ngFor="let list of matches">
    <match-row [match]="list"></match-row>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks Tyler, i have changed that but now ive got this ^^:
`EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Property binding ngFor not used by any directive on an embedded template ("
     <!-- Table -->
      <table class="table">
        [ERROR ->]<match-row *ngFor="let list of matches" [match]="list" >
        </match-row>
      </table>
"): MatchListComponent@11:8`

Comment: match-row added, see above

Comment: Jeah sure there is a simpler way to do this special case. Im new to angular2 and want to learn how to capsule those stuff into components to reuse it at another place. and add some row behavior for trainers and matchdays later (as i have also injected the services ^^)

Comment: You can keep the separation by moving the `<tr>` out to the parent component.

Comment: Nice try, but same issue on <tr> instead :/

Comment: Interesting.  Works fine for me.